# Convert old(uncompilable) .tex files that are exported from Scientific Workplace to new(compilable) .tex files?

Tags: scientific-workplace, convert

My question is a little bit odd.

So I have .tex files that are created by Scientific Workplace's old version (version available in 2014). When I try to use them in Texmaker for Mac I encounter with `tcibkpk.sty` not found error. When I look to the code I see also " `\input{tcilatex}`" line  before "`\begin{document}`" line.

So I am very new to this LaTeX world so I couldn't find anything in the web. As a final note I have a book in this tex file so I just can't type the document from the scratch. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can try commenting out the `\input{tcilatex}` line and see if any errors occur?

Comment: How did you "export" the SWP version of the document to LaTeX? There are two ways to do it, and only one is not going to give you grief.

Comment: Usually anything tci related in swp are only used internationally in swp and can be safely outcommented.

Comment: a simple google search finds copies of that file all over the internet, [for example here](https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/tcibkpk.sty) just put a copy in the same directory as your document.

Comment: @Troy Thanks that is what I had to do to solve the issue but it took 5 hours to debug all of the errors.

Comment: @Mico, he did not use save as/ portable Latex option, sadly.

Comment: @David Carlisle the link that you gave is dead and also I could not find any proper copies on the web. Even if I find, I am not sure where to put the document. But I managed to solve the issue by commenting out the TCI related codes. Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: @YiğitOkar uhh, an SWP doc not saved as **portable LaTeX**, you have my sympathies