# SWP5.5 LaTeX Error: File "`tcislid2." tex' not found

Tags: pdftex, miktex, compilation-error, winedt, scientific-workplace

I am compiling a LaTeX file created with SWP 5.5. But I was stuck by *LaTeX Error: File "`tcislid2." tex' not found*.

How can I solve it?
[image]

Some information:

I do know there are two ways to export the .tex file from SWP5.5 into other software like WinEdt and **I swear that I am using the right way (that is, save it as a "Portable LaTex" file)!**

The output in the screenshot is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Temp/swp0000.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-09-28>
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty))
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty)
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty)
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
(C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def)))

! LaTeX Error: File `tcislid2.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name:
```

I can find tcislid2.tex in *D:\swp55\TCITeX\TeX\LaTeX\SWmacros* on my computer.

I tried to compile this file with WinEdt but it returned the same *LaTeX Error: File "`tcislid2." tex' not found*.

Comment: Please always add links to your [crossposts](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=35374).

Comment: Your winedt does not look inside `D:\swp55\TCITeX\TeX\LaTeX\SWmacros`, you might been to copy the file into the same folder as the file you're looking at. Note that in most cases these `tci....` files that SWP uses can be ignored, perhaps with a few manually added macros.

Comment: Because of several issues with SWP 5.5 and because the license validation servers are expected to stop working in about 6 month, I would recommend to switch to another software as soon as possible. See “[Scientific Word LaTeX editor + MacKichan going out of business](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620030/277964)” for more information and suggestions.

Comment: Related: [Convert old(uncompilable) .tex files that are exported from Scientific Workplace to new(compilable) .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356947/277964) There are no answers to the question, but comments.

Comment: just copy the file to the folder with your document

Comment: @cabohah Thank you, but your link doesn't relate to my question. I know the correct way to export the .tex file from SWP5.5 into other softwares like WinEdt. I think the problem I met is because of SWP 5.5 is not compatible with the newest version of MikTeX. I decide to switch to an alternative LaTeX editor. Besides, why should I add links to my crossposts?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: @daleif Thank you, but that doesn't work for me either.

Comment: @RyokoAsakura → [Is cross-posting wrong (to an external site)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141823)

Comment: It has nothing to do with not being incompatible with MikTeX. Explain exactly what you did. Additionally did you export the SWP document to portable LaTeX? That should remove the tci stuff from the `.tex` file. Else outcomment it in WinEdt, more often than not they do nothing outside SWP.

Comment: @daleif Well, I am not very sure about whether the SWP is incompatible with MikTex. It is just my guess. I did what you indicated (copied the tcislid2.tex into the same directory as the .tex file I am editing) but the problem still arose. I am a novice to LaTeX, so I am sorry if I really misunderstood your words.

Comment: @daleif Yes, I REALLY export the SWP document to portable LaTeX, but the problem still arose.

Comment: Then try to outcomment the `\input{tcislid2.tex}` line (aka place a `%` in front, don't delete the line). Does it then compile, if not, which errors doc you get?

Comment: @daleif I have given up SWP5.5 anyway, because it can be troublesome if my .tex file produced with SWP5.5 is invalid on editors used by others, such as my advisor. Maybe you are right and all the discussions above can be helpful for someone else.

Comment: @daleif OK, I can continue to try to compile it with winedt. I have not deleted the .tex file generated by SWP.

Comment: @daleif `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.` This is what winedt returns after I change `\input{tcislid2.tex}` into `%\input{tcislid2.tex}`. The whole code is too long to be included in this comment.

Comment: Zip it up and send it to daleif at math.au.dk, then I'll have a look locally.

Comment: SWP has long been a pain. Usually portable LaTeX works fine, but then when you get a latex file from someone else SWP often cannot import it. It is not worth proceeding with SWP especially since the company behind it went bankrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that I asked a bad question. The best way to fix it is to uninstall SWP 5.5 and find an alternative editor. Though SWP 5.5 has powerful functions, it can cause many troubles as mentioned in the comments above. So SWP 5.5 is not a good choice overall.

Another mistake I made is crosspost. I should apologize for that. But I think [the answer of MjK in that post](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=35374&p=118592#p118592) provided some different ideas than comments above, which is also heuristic. But he also emphasized that SWP 5.5 is outmoded anyway.

Thank all of you again.

Comment: You still need to be able to convert your existing SWP files into compilable latex. A non-converted SWP file can be strange to edit manually in a different editor.